# PHP Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm developing an application in CodeIgniter, and I'm getting an error in sending mail while registering.

> PHP Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be
> constructors in a future version of PHP; emailcomm has a deprecated
> constructor in
> /var/www/html/portal/application/libraries/emailcomm.php on line 3

My Library file is below
**emailcomm.php**

```
class emailcomm
{
     
    var $to;
    var $subject;
    var $message;
    var $from='From:';    
    
    function emailcomm()
    {
        $this->CI=&get_instance();   
        ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
            ini_set("smtp_port","465");

            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
            $config['_smtp_auth']=TRUE;
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'contact-us@webtech.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'Web8*98*2015'; 
            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '60';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
            $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        
        $this->CI->load->library('email',$config); 
        
         $this->CI->email->initialize($config); 
    }
}
```

Recently upgraded the server to php7, and now my code doesn't work anymore. I'm going through the error logs showing the above error. How can I fix my code?

Comment: Are you using that function as a constructor? If so rename it to `__construct`

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. For more information read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). Using `var` is also deprecated in PHP5. Use [`private/protected/public`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) instead to control the access to the object properties from outside.

Comment: Note that `deprecated` means that it will be removed in the future (as stated in the message...). So it should still work and if you have problems, they are  caused by something else.

Answer (score 39):

**Solution** : Rename your function name **emailcomm()** to `__construct()`

**Explanation**: In previous versions of `PHP`, if `PHP` cannot find a `__construct()` function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class,
but now old style constructors are **DEPRECATED** in `PHP 7.0`, and will be removed in a future version. You should always use  `__construct()` in new code.
Read [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

```
   function __construct() {
      // copy your old constructor function code here
   }
```

Comment: What if there are multiple methods in class `emailcomm`?

Answer (score 10):

You can rename your `emailcomm()` function with `__construct()`:

```
function __construct()
```

instead of

```
function emailcomm()
```

or you can use the following `error_reporting` in your config file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `__construct` instead of a function with the same name as your class :

```
class Emailcomm
{

var $to;
var $subject;
var $message;
var $from='From:';    

function __construct()
{
    $this->CI=&get_instance();   
    ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
        ini_set("smtp_port","465");

        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['_smtp_auth']=TRUE;
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'contact-us@webtech.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'Web8*98*2015'; 
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '60';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";

    $this->CI->load->library('email',$config); 

     $this->CI->email->initialize($config); 
}
}
```

and just for coding standard, use CamelCase for your class name starting with a capital.

And one more thing, IMHO you may need to use a **DotEnv** library for handling your configuration, because writing that down in code is a bit messy.

Comment: if i write function __construct() {    like this how  can i add my function ( emailcomm() )within this ??

Comment: It's a constructor, I mean you don't need to call that function, just `new Emailcomm()` will automatically execute the code in the constructor (`__construct`)

Comment: I have 4 functions with in the class . no need to give function email(){  OR function sendmail{   like these ???

Comment: Only the functions with the same name as the class are causing the issue, the other functions will work just fine

Comment: Emailcomm here class name first letter mandatory ??  AND can i load library like this ?  $this->load->library('Emailcomm');

Comment: Not mandatory, just best practice and respecting coding standards :) ...

Comment: You welcome, if it helps you can accept it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`  - Remove this line in your application files in `application_top.php` and put this line of code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```

because latest php versions could not be supported deprecated files