# Methods with the same name as their class will

Tags: php

I am working on building second instance environment of existing PHP application.
Another words - I have one working instance and trying to setup copy of it.

And for some reason I have PHP error on my COPY (500 error):

```
Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version 
of PHP; SQL has a deprecated constructor.
```

Yes, I know about `__construct()` that should be used instead the same function name as a class name, but... the same code is working on MASTER instance.

I can`t change code, so, I need to find differences between master and copy envs.

Any suggestions with this?

I checked:

- PHP version the same on both instances (7.2.24)
- PHP configuration:

It can be a little bit different for default settings but Master instance have Apache with this directive: `PHPINIDir /var/custom/php` and in this dir `php.ini` file located.
I am using the same, I checked it, so, I believe most important part of config is the same.

- I read about `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED` - it can help. So yes, I checked custom PHP ini file - it has this setting.

Any other ideas? Why the same code is working on one instance but not with other?
This error was generated by `fatfree` framework.

I need more ideas what I can check else =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56791079/2292368

Comment: It is not duplicate

Comment: Use `phpinfo()` on both servers to check the actual configuration that's in place. Also check any framework config, such as a "development" or "debug" mode which might be promoting this notice to an error. (I know nothing about that framework, so can't be more specific.)

Comment: The error in itself is only a deprecation warning, that on its own should not cause a 500 error. _"This error was generated by fatfree framework."_ - then that probably comes with its own error handler, and it appears to be configured differently on your two systems - so that it throws a fatal error on deprecation warnings like this one, on your "copy" system. Go check the framework configuration/settings regarding the error handling.